# How do I stop Zend_Form::isValid from removing the values of submit buttons?

Tags: forms, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a Zend_Form object that generates a form in my view.

It does POST processing and submits data to my database.

Sometimes, I notice that my submit button, which simply says "Update Your Changes" is stripped of its value, so its just a button with no text value.  I'm surprised Zend_Form is not coded to ignore clearing values from submit buttons.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the value forcefully in the decorator:

```
<?php echo $this->element->update_btn->setLabel('Update Your Changes');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [s-rupali's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3872652/s-rupali) answer, you might also try `isValidPartial()`. This method, regardless of how you implement it (I'm a c# kinda guy) will not validate disabled elements You can then temporarily set your button to disabled, whilst the submission occurs. Afterwards, you can create another method to re-enable it.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.validate